# Changing Person & Group value by string in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have  list which has a column typed "Person & Group". I also have these Persons' name surname as string. How can i import these string data to Person & Group field?

Thanks in Advence.

Answer (score 0):

If the View in your List is turned into Datasheet you can Copy & Paste the values Directly.
(You just need the fullname of the persons)